# Odoo One2Many table creates line when pressing enter

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, one2many

I made a relational table in my own created object called typology.
here's how the thing works there’s a field in which you have to enter something like 1+1 or 2+3+4 and for each number in this field lines are created on this typology table, so the only thing that allows creation of lines in this table it's this field.

Now for each line I have to fill it with integers there are two columns Gross Weight and Tare, everything seems fine but when I’m filling the last fields in the typology table tree even though I have create=false if I press enter to enter the value it creates a new line.

```xml
<field name="typology_table" attrs="{'readonly':[('completed_flag','=',True)]}" class="table_w_symbol_label">
    <tree editable="bottom" create="false" open="false" delete="false">
        <field name="axis" readonly="1"/>
        <field name="position" readonly="1"/>
        <field name="tare"/>
        <field name="symbol" style="width:2%"/>
        <field name="gross_weight"/>
        <field name="symbol" style="width:2%"/>
    </tree>     
</field>
```

Anyone have any idea on how I can prevent this from happening.
Thanks in advance for the help!

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiMJZ.png)

NOTE:

I'm developing my module in my local computer but I upload it to an instance so I can make some tests, the problem persist in this instance but not locally, there are several differences for example when I print a report locally it's bigger than the development instance report. I don't get it bc they both have exactly the same modules

Comment: Are your local and external instances the same operating system? You should make sure that both are using the exact same core code (`git log -1` from each instance). Additionally, the difference in report size is probably due to differences in `wkhtmltopdf` between the two instances. Check each with `wkhtmltopdf -V` and see if they match. Even if those match, if they are two different operating systems, there may still be differences.

Comment: only the local instance is runned on my local computer the other ones are hosted in a server, i though of that before i have to check it out. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```xml
<field name="typology_table" attrs="{'readonly':[('completed_flag','=',True)]}" class="table_w_symbol_label" options="{'no_create': True}">
```

instead of using the create attr on the tree.

Comment: it didn't worked, i tried adding a widget for one2many but i'm still having this problem.